Assigning ClusterIP in Nodeport Kubernetes Services
currently I am using Nodeport service of Kubernetes Services now its generating Cluster IP , But I want to assign Cluster IP my self as a static one. So can I use Nodeport and still assign Cluster IP? but with different types and targeting same ports in the pods. Can I do this?

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: clusterip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: latest
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: endpoint
      port: 80
      targetPort: endpoint
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: latest
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: endpoint
      port: 80
      targetPort: endpoint
  externalIPs:
    - 100.02.33
---

I have tried to look in Kubernetes documentation and didn't find any.

I don't think you can manually assign the ClusterIP addresses.  Why would you want to?  The Kubernetes-internal DNS system means, within the cluster, you can use the Service's name nodeport to reach the Service regardless of its internal IP address.

I need to use the cluster IP in an Azure function each time it restarts the IP is changing and it is a problem for me. I want to keep it static is it possible? But I want to use nodeport service.

It does look like it's possible; if you manually fill in a value for clusterIP: in the Service spec then it will apparently be honored if possible.  It doesn't matter that it's a NodePort-type Service.  But, to repeat, you should never need to know this IP address; it's unreachable from outside the cluster, and inside the cluster you should use DNS.
